# Running cvat-server with docker-compose throws error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cvat

Anyone can help? I configured the following docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  cvat_postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:cvat
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/cvat/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  cvat_redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    command: redis-server #--requirepass cvat
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/cvat/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./volumes/cvat/redis/data:/var/lib/redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master

  cvat_server:
    image: openvino/cvat_server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - CVAT_POSTGRES_HOST=cvat_postgres
      - CVAT_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=cvat
      - CVAT_REDIS_HOST=cvat_redis
    #volumes:
      ./volumes/cvat/data:/home/django/data
    depends_on:
      - cvat_postgres
      - cvat_redis

  cvat_ui:
    image: openvino/cvat_ui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - cvat_server
```

Running `dockcer-compose up --build` it throws the following error:

```sh
cvat_server_1    | Error: Format string '%(ENV_HOME)s/wait-for-it.sh %(ENV_CVAT_POSTGRES_HOST)s:5432 -t 0 -- bash -ic \\\n"rm -f /tmp/cvat-server/httpd.pid && python3 ~/manage.py migrate && \\\npython3 ~/manage.py collectstatic --no-input && \\\nexec python3 $HOME/manage.py runmodwsgi --log-to-terminal --port 8080 \\\n--limit-request-body 1073741824 --log-level INFO --include-file ~/mod_wsgi.conf \\\n%(ENV_DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS)s --locale %(ENV_LC_ALL)s \\\n--server-root /tmp/cvat-server"' for 'program:runserver.command' contains names ('ENV_DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS') which cannot be expanded. Available names: ENV_CVAT_POSTGRES_HOST, ENV_CVAT_POSTGRES_PASSWORD, ENV_CVAT_REDIS_HOST, ENV_DJANGO_CONFIGURATION, ENV_HOME, ENV_HOSTNAME, ENV_LANG, ENV_LC_ALL, ENV_PATH, ENV_TERM, ENV_TZ, ENV_USER, ENV_http_proxy, ENV_https_proxy, ENV_no_proxy, ENV_socks_proxy, group_name, here, host_node_name, process_num, program_name in section 'program:runserver' (file: 'supervisord.conf')
cvat_server_1    | For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Summarizing: `Error: Format string '...' for 'program:runserver.command' contains names ('ENV_DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS') which cannot be expanded.`

It is complaining with ENV_DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS, but in https://hub.docker.com/r/openvino/cvat_server, all django environment variables are optional.

Comment: That looks like an error in how the image is constructed. The obvious workaround would be to set `ENV_DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS` to an empty string in your `docker-compose.yaml`.

Comment: (You can see where that variable is used [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/blob/04ac49a73851f350f8334a45dc29aa75808b8ef0/supervisord.conf#L66)).